# Select recent date for multiple phones

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

REQ: If multiple phones have the same most recent date, take the phone with the lowest number. My data is like as below.

```
CustomerID PhoneNumber  CreatedDate

  1111      1234587        2013-09-10
  1111      1243557        2013-09-11
  1111      3214562        2009-12-01
  2222      7654312        2013-02-05
  2222      6544343        2006-07-23
  2222      7652135        2006-04-16
  2222      5672851        2010-11-16
  2222      4726722        1998-06-18
```

Output will be like:

```
CustomerID  PhoneNumber  CreatedDate
 1111         1234587     2013-09-10
 2222         4726722     1998-06-18
```

Comment: Edit the question add sample output based on sample data.

Comment: Go back to whoever gave you that requirement and ask for clarification.   NONE of the rows in your data have the same date.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT 
    YT.CreatedDate
    ,MIN(YT.PhoneNumber) 
FROM
    YourTable YT
GROUP BY
    YT.CreatedDate
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Mili! But my output is based on minimum CreatedDate not on PhoneNumber.

Comment: @NagaSushmaKallam Good to hear you have found a solution please remove the accepted mark from this answer since it is clearly wrong and having an incorrect answer marked as accepted will be confusing and perhaps misleading for others reading this question in the future (Sorry Mili).

Answer (score 0):

Use two sub-queries to determine max date and min phone number and join them with the table itself

```
SELECT a.CustomerID, a.PhoneNumber, a.CreatedDate
FROM test a
JOIN (SELECT CustomerID, MAX(CreatedDate) as max_date
      FROM test 
      GROUP BY CustomerID) b ON b.CustomerID = a.CustomerID AND
                                b.max_date = a.CreatedDate
JOIN (SELECT CustomerID, CreatedDate, MIN(PhoneNumber) min_number
      FROM test 
      GROUP BY CustomerID, CreatedDate) c ON c.CustomerID = a.CustomerID AND 
                                             c.min_number = a.PhoneNumber AND 
                                             c.CreatedDate = a.CreatedDate
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! but when we say TOP 1 from the table, it'll give only one value. But my output should be like for one customer id one phone number should come based on created date. Any suggestions please.

Comment: @NagaSushmaKallam I have updated my answer now that I better understand the question

Comment: @NagaSushmaKallam any feedback on this?

Comment: thanks for the help! I have used the Rank () Over PARTITION by function to get the accurate result.

Comment: @NagaSushmaKallam Maybe you could post your solution as an answer to help others.

Comment: and here is the solution.                                                                                                                                      select * into #testtemp from
(select CustomerID,PhoneNumber,CreatedDate,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC,PhoneNumber asc) rank_nbr 
from dbo.yourtable) a  
where rank_nbr =1

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
SELECT TOP 1 CreatedDate, MIN(CAST(PhoneNumber AS INT))
FROM [TABLENAME]
GROUP BY CAST(CreatedDate AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is using the `WITH TIES` clause in-concert with `Row_Number()`

**Example**

```
Select Top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By CustomerID Order By CreatedDate Desc,PhoneNumber)
```

**Returns**

```
CustomerID  PhoneNumber CreatedDate
2222        7654312     2013-02-05
1111        1243557     2013-09-11
```

Comment: @NagaSushmaKallam Happy to help, but why would you accept which looks like the wrong answer ?